# Is this function odd?

Tags: calculus

> $f: (-\infty, \infty)\to \left(-\dfrac{\pi}{2},
>  \dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$, $f(x)= 2\arctan(e^x)-\dfrac {\pi}2$

I would like to know if the above function is odd or not.

The particular problem I am facing with it is this:

$f(x)+ f(-x)=  2(\arctan(e^u)+ \arctan(e^{-u})- \pi$ which **tends to** $0$ but is not exact $0$. So I believe that this function shouldn't be odd.

Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**

Taking into account the fact that for $t>0$ ,  we have

$$\arctan(t)+\arctan(\frac1t)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

and for each $x\in\Bbb R\; , \;e^x>0$, so we can write

$$\arctan(e^x)+\arctan(e^{-x})=\frac\pi2$$

thus

$$f(-x)=2\arctan(e^{-x})-\frac\pi2=$$
$$-\Bigl(2\arctan(e^x)-\frac\pi2\Bigr)=-f(x)$$

the function is ODD.